# Windows 11 - Not kind sort command for viewing all files in subfolders

Tags: windows, file, sorting, command

I used to use a sort command when trying to view all files across a bunch of folders at once. It makes sorting files easier. I do know part of the command was written as not sort kind, however I am unable to remember which parts need to be capitalised, and where the colon (:) goes. I have trying googling the answer, and even gone through hours of YouTube videos trying to find the answer. I would prefer not to use the asterisk (*) command  or the DIR command [Screenshot showing one of many attempted iterations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mn12z.png)as that is not suitable for my use. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have since been alerted on StackExchange that the answer to the issue I was having is kind:NOT Folder.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).